# Beta or Incomplete Beta Integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, beta-function

I have derived along the way and I have reached a situation as below. After further research on myself, I noticed it has a pattern as Beta/Incomplete Beta Function. Could anyone please give me some light on how to integrate the function below?

$$\int_{\frac{\theta}{u+\theta}}^{1}x^{\alpha-(k+1)}(1-x)^{k} dx$$

Comment: Consider splitting the limits into $\int_{\theta/(u+\theta)}^1 =\int_{0}^1-\int_{0}^{\theta/(u+\theta)}$ where the first is a beta function and the second an incomplete beta function.